# Convert time to a float

Tags: javascript, timer, stopwatch

I've got a stopwatch app that stores the times in an array. The JS counts milliseconds from when the timer is started, then converts those milliseconds into seconds and minutes, and outputs that as a string.

What I'm trying to do is calculate the averages of these times, so I have to convert the strings into floats. It can convert a string like 10.35 to a float just fine, but it obviously doesn't work with something like 1:24.56, that's what I'm trying to fix. The time will be in one of these formats:

```
[seconds].[milliseconds]
[minutes]:[seonds].[milliseconds]
```

Any ideas? I'm really new with Javascript so I'm not sure where to go with this.

EDIT: The repo is [here](https://github.com/Treedot/PolyTimer). All of the nonsense happens in the timer.js and main.js files.

Comment: How about averaging the millisecond values and converting the result into the correct format ?

Comment: I had this idea last night but I wasn't sure if it would work. I'm going to give it a shot now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just split it, and add it up:

```
function toMS(str) {
  if(!str.includes(":"))
     return parseFloat(str);
  const [mins, secms] = str.split(":");
  const [sec, ms] = secms.split(".");
  return ((+mins * 60) + +sec) * 1000 + +ms;
}
```

*(This uses "unary plus operators" to convert the strings into numbers)*

Comment: Since I'm not using hours in this timer, I changed some of the wording, but I'm getting an undefined error for what I replaced minsec with.

Comment: @treedot so thats mins:seconds.ms ?

Comment: Yes, for the purpose of this timer, it will likely never need to go over an hour.

Comment: @treedo there you go

Comment: Thanks. So I'm running my formattedTime output from the timer.js through this function and logging it in the console, like so: console.log(toMS(formattedTime)) and I'm still getting that secms is undefined.

Comment: Is it really "something like 1:24.56" ?

Comment: Yeah, check out the timer.js in the repo. It outputs whatever it says on the timer itself. Something over a minute would be outputted as 1:24.25 etc.

Comment: Because [it works](http://jsbin.com/tugasoyuwa/edit?console) for what you presented in the question. Its not my job to dig through a repos code, its your job to present ypur question accurately :), what happens if its under a minute?

Comment: If it's under a minute it works when converted to a float because it outputs something like 45.09 etc. See now the weird thing is, my console is still logging the milliseconds but I'm still getting the undefined error anyways. Even though it's working.

Comment: @treedo edited so that it hopefully also works for secs only